# Is it possible to return multiple rows in a Firebird's stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

I was wondering if is possible to return more than one row found in a `SELECT` query in Firebird 1.5, like below:

```
| FIELD1 | FIELD 2 |
--------------------
| 1.00   | 1       |
| 2.00   | 2       |
| 3.00   | 3       |

SET TERM /;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
RETURNS (VARIABLE1 DOUBLE PRECISION, VARIABLE2 INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE INTO :VARIABLE1, :VARIABLE2;
END/

EXECUTE PROCEDURE TEST/

SET TERM ;/
```

Assuming the query returns more than one result/row, the following error is thrown:

> Statement failed, SQLCODE = -811
>
> Multiple rows in singleton select

Obviously, the Firebird's engine doesn't allow me to return more than one value in a variable. I'm developing a Python's software where I want to get, as a tuple, for example, something like this [(1.00, 1), (2.00, 2), (3.00, 3)], based on the procedure TEST. I'm using the kinterbasdb module to connect with the GDB.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900648/how-to-execute-procedure-returning-resultset-in-firebird

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you still using kinterbasdb? It has been superseded by drivers like [FDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fdb/) and [firebirdsql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/firebirdsql).

Answer (score 10):

Firebird has two [types of stored procedures](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-storedprocs-types):

- Executable procedures produce at most one row, and are executed using:

  ```
    execute procedure <procedurename>
  ```
- Selectable procedures can produce multiple rows and are executed using:

  ```
    select * from <procedurename>
  ```

  Or with parameters:

  ```
    select * from <procedurename>(param, ...)
  ```

A selectable procedures contains the `SUSPEND` keyword which outputs the row and waits for the next fetch. Presence of this keyword is the only thing that distinguishes between the two types.

Warning: It is possible to use `execute procedure` with a selectable procedure, but in that case it will only produce a single row, and execution will end after that first row has been produced: the rest of the stored procedure after `SUSPEND` will not be executed! It also used to be possible to 'select' from an executable stored procedure, but in Firebird 3 that is no longer possible.

The specific reason of the error *"Multiple rows in singleton select"* is the line:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE INTO :VARIABLE1, :VARIABLE2;
```

This [`select ... into ...`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select-into) statement is only allowed to produce a single row (a.k.a. a singleton select). If you expect more than one row, you need to use [`for select ... into ... do`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-forselect), which allows you to iterate over the resulting rows.

Combining this with `suspend` will then result in:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
RETURNS (VARIABLE1 DOUBLE PRECISION, VARIABLE2 INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE INTO :VARIABLE1, :VARIABLE2
  DO
  BEGIN
      SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

The `BEGIN ... END`-block is technically not necessary, but I prefer to always use a block here.

You can then execute this with:

```
select variable1, variable2 from test;
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is called "Selectable Stored Procedure". Basically, you must change your code to something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE TEST
RETURNS (VARIABLE1 DOUBLE PRECISION, VARIABLE2 INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  for SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2 FROM TABLE INTO :VARIABLE1, :VARIABLE2
   do SUSPEND;
END
```

and call the procedure with a SELECT, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

Comment: See also https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-storedprocs.html#fblangref25-psql-storedprocs-types

Comment: In these cases why not use Views? Is there any difference?